# Compute the vertical motion of the Rindler's length contraction paradox

Tags: special-relativity

Suppose a rod with length $L$ moving toward a hole whose radius is $L$. The paradox is, from the ground frame, the length of the rod is contracted hence rod will fall into the hole. However, from the rod's frame, it is the length of the hole contracted, so the rod will not fall. Now, ask to find the vertical motion of the rod within these two perspectives.

From the gound frame:
$$
y(t)=\frac{1}{2}gt^2
$$

From the rod's frame, due to the Lorentz transformation, the vertical motion of the front of the rod is
$$
y(t)=y'_{front}(t')=\frac{1}{2}g\gamma^2(t'+\frac{vx'}{c^2})^2
$$
However, it is where I begin to confuse. For example, how to compute the $y'_{back}(t')$? Obviously $\Delta t'\neq0$, and it is equaled to
$$
\Delta t'=-\gamma\frac{v\Delta x'}{c^2}=-\gamma\frac{vL}{c^2}
$$
Can anyone tell me if I am correct so far and if so how to compute $y'_{back}(t')$ properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that your second equation belongs not only to the front end of the rod but also to any point on the rod at a distance $x'$ from the observer located at the hind end of the rod. For the front end, you had better substitute $x'=L'$, and for the hind end where the observer is located use $x'=0$. Therefore, we have:

$$y'_{front}(t')=\frac{1}{2}g\gamma^2(t'+\frac{vL'}{c^2})^2\space,$$

$$y'_{hind}(t')=\frac{1}{2}g\gamma^2t'^2\space.$$

Comment: But is there existed time dilation, because at the beginning I thought the front of the rod and the end of the rod fall in different time in the rocket frame.

Comment: @oscarmetalbreak They do. If the hind end falls at $t'=0$, the front end has already fallen at $t'=-L'/v$ from the viewpoint of the observer located at the hind end of the rod.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you also familiar with the detonator paradox where there is a T shape structure moving toward the U shape structure(detonator). Such that In the rest frame (U's perspective) the explosion won't happen, whereas, in the moving frame (T's perspective), the explosion happens. Suppose I know the moving velocity $v$, the length of the arm of T, and the depth of the U. Do you know how to quantitively show the explosion happen in two frames?

Comment: @oscarmetalbreak You're welcome. Ask it as a new question, then I can answer it.

Comment: My prof posts an answer I will see if I can understand that. Thank you so much.